Exit efi shell in startup.nsh
I have a USB that automatically installs a BIOS version in a PC that has USB priority to boot up.
This is part of my startup.nsh script in the folder USB:/EFI/BOOT/:
if exist fs0:\bios_version then
    if exist fs0:\bios_version\V41 then
        echo "BIOS Version V41 already installed. Please remove the USB Drive and restart the device"
        exit
    else
        rm fs0:\bios_version
        mkdir fs0:\bios_version
    endif
else
    mkdir fs0:\bios_version
endif

It checks if it has already been installed, if so, it proceeds to exit.
When I boot the PC with the USB connected the script fails and tells: "if: IF has no corresponding ENDIF(line 71)" and ends the script back to EFI shell.
Line 71 is the else below exit. And it just stays there, in the EFI shell waiting for a command.
However, if execute startup.nsh myself it does exit the EFI shell without any errors and boots up the Operating system.
It is the second behaviour what I am looking for, but I want it to work automatically. So why is this happening?
